# How should I make my Asp.Net Core web apps available online for beta testing?

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-core

Should I run my own webserver? If so, how do I do that? I'm running on Windows 10 with VS2017, IIS Express and MS SQL Server.

I don't need a domain name. Just providing access via IP-address is fine. I'm just looking for a cheap and easy way of enabling other people to help me beta test my apps.

Can Azure be used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want a proper host that is managed by another team.  Azure, or any other cloud provider would be able to do that for you very well.  Alternatively you can just hunt for a web host that supports Net Core.  In all cases you will have a domain name, but it might just be a subdomain until you actually register a proper domain name yourself.

**Self-Hosting**

- Riskiest prospect since you have to have a machine on all the time that external users can hit.  Not all of them are good citizens.  If you are not a security expert, just drop this from your list
- Requires an always on machine
- Requires a static IP address--most home ISPs cycle IP addresses for your house.
- You are responsible for everything, from security, to OS patching, to installation and backups

**3rd-Party Hosting**

- Can be a very inexpensive option if you can find a host that has everything you need
- You have the least control over how things are deployed
- Typically you have shared hosting with other websites.  Any one of those other websites can impact how yours performs

**Cloud Hosting**

- Many providers have packages that are attractive
- You can spin down your servers when you don't want to pay the monthly fee
- Your app is the only one in the virtual environment, so you have good isolation
- Typically very good monitoring

**Azure Hosting (specifically)**

- Everything with standard cloud hosting
- You can set up a post-commit hook on your git repository for Azure to pull the latest code, compile it, and deploy it for you

In terms of ease of use, the Azure solution will be the best option, and provides a neat and easy way to do continuous delivery for beta testing.  The simpler your application, the easier the deployment.  That said, there are several trade-offs.  One of them being the cost of hosting.  Having a host you can turn off when you don't need it without requiring a monthly fee to maintain a contract can be a good thing.  That said, you'll have to do the math and see what works for your project specifically.